# Why isn't this switch statement return that 0 is in 0-100?

Tags: php, switch-statement

**Information**

I am currently making a user level system for my website. I have a points column in my users table that will get incremented on certain awards and milestones etc.

**Problem**

I have this switch statement that takes the users points and converts them into a level that gets returned. But it is saying that "0" isn't in 0-100 option, and rather in the 100-200 option.

```
function userLevel($points){

    switch ($points) {
        case ($points>=0 && $points<100):
            return 1; // Level 1
            break;
        case ($points>=100 && $points <200):
            return 2; // Level 2
            break;
        case ($points>=200 && $points<300):
            return 3; // Level 3
            break;
        case ($points>=300 && $points<400):
            return 4; // Level 4
            break;
    }

}

echo userLevel(0);
```

I feel like this is one of those "You have been coding too much for one sitting" questions and the answer is right in front of me, but I just can't see it!

Comment: cases cannot contain conditions. it just expects one scalar value.

Comment: @DanLee I think this is legal for PHP.

Comment: @DanLee They can contain conditions, but the behavior isn't what's expected.  What has happened here is that `0` is being treated like `false`. The first condition matches, and returns `true`, hence not zero. The second is false, and matches.  Any of the subsequent cases would match but it breaks on the first one.

Comment: If you want to use `switch` in that way, then you must make it `switch(true)` and then have cases with conditions that become true or false.

Comment: switch can only be used with integervalues, not with conditions. If you want to check conditions, you have to use if-statements.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes this isn't what I meant. It may contain conditions but this condition is of course evaluated to `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your using conditions for your cases, you probably want to switch on `TRUE`:

```
function userLevel($points){

    switch (true) {
        case ($points>=0 && $points<100):
            return 1; // Level 1
            break;
        case ($points>=100 && $points <200):
            return 2; // Level 2
            break;
        case ($points>=200 && $points<300):
            return 3; // Level 3
            break;
        case ($points>=300 && $points<400):
            return 4; // Level 4
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: This syntax is uggly and should be discouraged

Comment: That's just your opinion

Comment: @RaphaëlMalié I need it like this as the points thresholds will be changing therefore I cannot do it with a algorithm. And thanks sroes, accepting the answer now.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is your code is becoming this

```
function userLevel($points){

    switch (0) {
        case (true):  // compare 0 to true
            return 1; // Level 1
            break;
        case (false):  // compare 0 to false 
            return 2; // Level 2
            break;
        case (false):
            return 3; // Level 3
            break;
        case (false):
            return 4; // Level 4
            break;
    }

}

echo userLevel(0);
```

The first case does not match because `0 != true`

the second case does match because `0 == false`

Therefore the second option runs

as others have said use true in the switch so then it becomes  `true == true` as the first case, making that run

Answer (score 2):

One other thing you can do to eliminate a lot of code for this is to simply do this

```
return floor(($points+100)/100);
```